# In KVM how to clone a VM to a VM with different disk space

Tags: virtual, virtualization, kvm

Using Centos 6.7 as hot for KVM virtualization, I have created a VM with a virtual disk of size 30GB. I want to clone this VM to a new VM with a different disk size. 
The new VM should have a disk space of 60GB.
Is this possible at all? if yes how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

why you want clone vm to deferent space ?
1 - if you want clone vm for extend hdd of vm 
 kvm use lvm for each vm so you can extend lvm for increase hdd of vm

```
 lvextend -l +(size of extend in byte or use G for gigabyte) /dev/vgname/lvmNameOfVm
resize2fs /dev/vgname/lvmNameOfVm
```

you can find lvm and vg name with `lvdisplay` and `vgs`

2 - if you need clone for change location of vm to other server
i suggested you first resize your vm and then clone to new vm

note : if you want do this for first time first create a vm for test and do it after test it and work for you use for main vm

you have not controlpanel like solusvm ? if you have your panel can clone vm withouth need do anything on the ssh

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to use your solution, but I think I should increase disk size in host machine and then use lvextend in guest OS to change partitions. am I correct?

Comment: first should extend lvm from host machin and  for usage this space in the guest os need extend on that guest os

Answer (score 1):

I managed to clone a VM and then increase its disk size and because I decided to bring steps I took here because I couldn't find all these steps in one place.
after cloning, to extend the disk size, create a disk with bigger size:

```
virsh vol-create-as default newdisk 60G
```

and copy the old disk to the new disk and expand one of the guest's partition:

```
virt-resize --expand /dev/sda2   olddisk newdisk
```

change the vm's configuration to use the new disk.
issue this command to edit the configuration file:

```
#virsh edit <VM_name>
```

find and replace the old disk name with the new disk name.

more detail about these steps can be found here: http://libguestfs.org/virt-resize.1.html 
now start the new vm, log in to it and resize the vm's lvm partion.

```
lvextend -l +<free_blocks_count> /dev/vg_<VM_name>/lv_root
resize2fs /dev/vg_<VM_NAME>/lv_root
```

to find number of free blocks issue the following command:

```
vgdisplay
```

a great tutorial about these steps can be found here: http://www.tecmint.com/extend-and-reduce-lvms-in-linux/